# Biblatex note appears twice

Tags: biblatex

I add a note to my reference as the reference in the bibliography does not show the volume etc.
I want the following reference:
[image]

Without the note the volume and pages are not shown but with the note it appears twice.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, style=apa, sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle, english = british]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\parencite{b20_taskforce_open_2017}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and the following bib entry:

```
@incollection{heckman1999,
  title={The economics and econometrics of active labor market programs},
  author={Heckman, James J and LaLonde, Robert J and Smith, Jeffrey A},
  booktitle={Handbook of labor economics},
  volume={3},
  pages={1865--2097},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Elsevier},
  note = {Vol. 3, pp. 1865-2097},
  doi = {10.1016/S1573-4463(99)03012-6},
  url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1573446399030126}
}
```

Comment: Step 1 is https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/121. But there is something else going on in your example.

Comment: There is also the quirk that `style=apa,` apparently only show the "In" if there was an editor. That might also be considered a bug.